# accidentally rolled back to a previous commit in git

Tags: git, heroku, github

I am new to Git and not sure what I did wrong. I have bunch of branches along side master for example - filling-layout, data-upload, sign-in-out etc. I had moved on to a new branch, when I had to change something in my layout. So I thought it would be better to go back to filling-layout branch and make the changes there. So I typed in `git checkout filling-layout` and that erased a bunch of things that I had in the layout and its back to a previous version and all my changes disappeared. I thought I had committed filling-layout after all my changes and uploaded it to github and heroku.

- Any idea how I can get it back?
- Also can anyone explain why this could happen?
- What are the best practices when you have to make a small change that
  could potentially go into the previously committed branch?
- Is it better to make a new branch or you can checkout the existing
  branch to make the change.

Comment: It sounds like your newer work may still be there. Check out the branch on which you did your newer work and see if it comes back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking out the previous branch.

This might work

```
git checkout -
```

It will try to checkout the branch you were on before the current one (analogous to `cd -`).

Once you have committed your changes in git it is very difficult to loose them. Checking out a branch will change the working tree to match what is in that branch, but switching back will restore the state of the working tree to that of the previous branch.

Another way to find previous commits is by using `git reflog`. That will list what commits HEAD has been at, and using the hash you can checkout any of those.

Comment: Thanks Klas. So should I try to type in the command as you have mentioned or put the branch name.

Comment: @amey1908 either will do fine. `git checkout -` is nice if you forget what branch it was.

Comment: git is not allowing me to checkout another branch since I get the error, Error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: .idea/workspace.xml. So I added .idea/ to my .gitignore, but I have to commit my changes before I checkout another branch. I am afraid this commit will overwrite my filling-layout branch which has deleted all my changes. Should that be ok?

Comment: +1 for the `-` notation. I didn't know about that, even though I use `cd -` a thousand times a day.

Comment: @amey1908 It will be ok. Committing changes to `filling-layout` will not overwrite other commits. In fact, you can't change existing commits in Git, and you can always get back to the state of a commit. That is one of the strengths of Git

Comment: @KlasMellbourn - that worked! Did this happen because I had committed part of my filling-layout with a later branch? Also what is the best practice if I have to change the layout again - create a new branch or go to a previously committed branch - `filling-layout`?

Comment: @amey1908 Yes it sounds like it. I would say that best practice would be to use each branch for a specific purpose. If a change is due to that purpose, do it in that branch. Also, once the purpose is fulfilled, merge the branch to master, so that other branches and developers may take advantage of the changes.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: I keep getting this error when I commit and try to switch branch - error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: .idea/workspace.xml. I have added .idea/* in my ignoregit. I accidentally deleted my files again, and as you mentioned moved to the previous branch but I didn't get it back. Is there a way to delete the entire git and pull it from remote and start fresh?